# Use quartz to run script at scheduled time by reading a config file

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

May I know is it possible to create a program which can read a config file and trigger some script(eg. shell script) with quartz? I would like to add new task from time to time, is it possible to do this by changing the config file only without changing the code itself? Would be grateful if someone can teach me how to do it if this is possible.

Comment: It is possible in java but cant you use corn job for scheduling shell scripts ?

Comment: I cannot schedule it with cron because cron is disable in my environment.Sorry for not mentioning that in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to add jobs and triggers at runtime:

- use API (you might wrap it in some web service or GUI)
- use JMX (similar as above but gives you an API over JMX)
- use [`XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin`](http://quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.1.0/org/quartz/plugins/xml/XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin.html) that reads jobs on startup from arbitrary XML file (so requires restart. See [my article](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.no/2012/04/quartz-scheduler-plugins-hidden.html) for more details and [`job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd`](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd) to explore XML format